# Prevent rails assets image-url helper extra 'img' word

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass, asset-pipeline, imageurl

In my SCSS file I'm using the Rails image-url helper like this:

```
background-image: image-url('sidebar-button-gradient.png')!important
```

It generates this two lines in the CSS as output:

```
background-image: url(/assets/sidebar-button-gradient.png) !important img;
background-image-width: 20px;
```

In Chrome inspector, the first line is ignored (it is crossed), if I manually remove the extra last 'img' word it is considered:

```
background-image: url(/assets/sidebar-button-gradient.png) !important;
```

Rails helper is generating it, how can I remove that word?

I tried also asset-url(path, image)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working:

```
 background: url(sidebar-button-gradient.png) repeat-x #f6f6f4;
```

Only rest to test in production, I'm not sure if it will work when the assets are precompiled.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SCSS, it should be trivial to [add Compass](http://compass-style.org/install/) on top of it (obviously, I say that without knowing much about your setup). If you're having trouble with the Rails image-url helper, try using [the image-url helper provided by compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#image-url). It has a similar or identical syntax and I've never had trouble with its output.